# Pass ID(Index) to onEditDetail() Parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, parameters, ngoninit

How can i pass the value index or id to EditDetail() parameters. I want it to be put inside the parenthesis of onEditDetail() once i click the onEditDetail() in html

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
      this.user = this.userService.getUser(this.id);
    });
}

onEditDetail(id: string) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

> user-detail.component.html

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class = "col-md-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          {{ user.l_name}} 's Complete Information<span class="pull-right"><input class="form-control" placeholder="Search User" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text"></span>
        </div> 
        <table class="table table-responsive">
          <thead class="thead-default">
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Contact Number</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{{ user.f_name }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.l_name }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.contact_no }}</td>
              <td><button class=" btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="onEditDetail()">Edit</button> </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other answers,

You need to understand that you are making an **asynchronous call.**

So If you need to access id anywhere else, you need to get that on completion of asynchronous call, not before that.

And this is reason, you need to call onEditDetail() inside Subscribe block as last parameter.
there are 3 params to subscribe.

1. Data which is returned by call,
2. Error if any occured.
3. On complete if you wish to do something.

In your case, as 3rd parameter, you have to call onEditDetail method

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
      this.user = this.userService.getUser(this.id);

      // 3rd parameter, this is where call is subscribe is completed
      this.onEditDetail(this.id);
    });
}
```

Comment: It says  Argument of type number is not assignable to parameter  of type string. And also want it to be a number. Thanks

Comment: @Joseph change your onEditDetail(id: string)  to onEditDetail(id: any)

Comment: Do you have any idea why theres a "+" sign in +params? what's the purpose?

Comment: @Joseph (+) converts string 'id' to a number

Comment: Thanks a lot. by the way, i added a an html above. Once i click the edit button, it should get the id(index), so I would be able to edit the item through accessing the ID. Is my code correct?

Comment: "user". If this is a model, you need to pass that model to your component with OnClick event as a parameter and in componenet you can access user.id. another way to do it is to pass $event with Onclick event and access it in component. If answer has helped please mark it as correct.

Comment: The problem is that i don't have a user.id. I want to get the index but my user-detail.component.html is not an array but it's an object

Comment: Check this out - https://angular.io/guide/user-input. How to get data from html in component

Comment: I know how to do it but i want to pass the index to my edit button just like  this "onEditDetail(index)"

Comment: To pass index to component, you have to make it available to html and then pass it

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I dont' have an array as you can see above because this is not a list of items but only one item is shown

Comment: yea. So you aren't showing ID on html, then how do you expect it to get in component. you can get firstname, lastname etc.

Comment: So how can pass it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153188/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-joseph).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
      this.user = this.userService.getUser(this.id);

      // Your method call
      this.onEditDetail(this.id);
    });
}

onEditDetail(id: string) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: It says  Argument of type number is not assignable to parameter  of type string. And also want it to be a number. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
      this.onEditDetail(this.id); //call onEditDetails and pass id to it.
      this.user = this.userService.getUser(this.id);
    });
}

onEditDetail(id: any) {
  console.log(id);
}
```